# How to combine Cardboard VR + Vuforia AR plugin on Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

Many people are getting good results combining these 2 plugins (Vuforia + Cardboard VR). One good example is CMOAR RPG: https://youtu.be/59wkhmPGPcI

My question is: how to achieve a result like that? As indicated on Cardboard VR official documentation, I used the stereoControl script inside my ARCamera and It worked in Play Mode. BUT when compiled, running on Android, The application just doesn't show stereo cameras, showing only the single camera.

A friend of mine said It's a matter of duplicating cameras, but I don't realize how to do this with success.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The propery tag for Unity3D is `unity3d`

Answer (score 1):

I did something like that by using [RenderTexture](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html)

The trick was render what the ARCamera (vuforia) into the texture and snap that texture on a plane that the CameraCardboard see.

if you can upgrade to Vuforia 5.0.5. there's a option to toggle the stereo view and on that point, you dont need Cardboard now.

Comment: Any chance you can elaborate on this? I am having a tough time trying to get this to work. I have the Latest Google Cardboard and Unity, so I know that is the root of the problem, however is there a way to get this to work with out using Cardboard at all?  I have a feeling that i tried to fix something that is already handled in the new version of Vuforia.

Comment: Vuforia goes very in details to do that on that page : https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Integrating-Cardboard-to-the-ARVR-Sample